# Trying to add a div above nav bar on the top of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Adding another div on top of the nav bar completely changes the layout of the nav bar itself. 
HTML-

```
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <div class="top-bar">
      <b>For sales inquiries</b>, call +1(866)965-1533 or <a>Request a free demo</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SignEasy</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-left:140px;">
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Industries <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">For Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">API</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-right:67px;">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" style="border-radius:12px;background:#3793EE;color:white;">Start free trial</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS-

```
.top-bar {
  text-align:right;
    background:#f4f4f4;
    color:black;
}
```

Getting a question mark on the top left of the page-https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2875140/418d9355f3a8c75b00d15a69d91b382b

Comment: For that you need to add separate div above the 'navbar-collapse'...

Comment: Above the nav bar collapse and below the first div?

Comment: Check the Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/xeaahey3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to add separate div above the `navbar-collapse`

Working Fiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xeaahey3/)

```css
.top-bar {
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
    <div class="top-bar">
      For sles inquiries, call +1(866)965-1533 or Request a free demo 
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SignEasy</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-left:140px;">
            <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Industries <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">For Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">API</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-right:67px;">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" style="border-radius:12px;background:#3793EE;color:white;">Start free trial</button>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this and the result I got is this -https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2875102/61e533e3ec4bb6d28789cd5c0be24749    The same thing happened before, the nav-bar gets completely misplaced

Comment: Hey, So it worked. But I am getting an odd QUESTION mark at the top left of the page. https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2875140/418d9355f3a8c75b00d15a69d91b382b

Comment: Hey this method works, but how do I get rid of the question mark though?

Comment: are you working with php or only html? IF you used php code then check it close proper.. i think any  <php> close tag was left so that it was display..

Comment: I am working with only html css. Have not used any PHP. I updated my code into the question.

Comment: Could there be a conflict between scripts or link tags? Should I include all the script link tags i have used in the webpage? Since I have also used jQuery

Comment: you can send your demo link..  so i can check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156246/discussion-between-yohanelly-and-minal-chauhan).

Answer (score 0):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQJx7.png)
First, you should use

> `<nav class="navbar navbar-default">`

After that,
Check here [please](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

Comment: hey, So i have got it to work but i am getting a question mark on the top left of the page. I dont know  why and how to get rid of it. Help me out please? https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2875140/418d9355f3a8c75b00d15a69d91b382b

Comment: add css link to your html page.
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
mystyle.css:
.top-bar {
  text-align:right;
    background:#f4f4f4;
    color:black;
}

Comment: where do i add this? Inside the <style> tag or in the <body> or in the <head> tag?

Comment: you can use <style> .top-bar {
  text-align:right;
    background:#f4f4f4;
    color:black;
}</style>

Comment: Yes I have already used that in my css, as i have uploaded above. You're saying it should be in a separate <style> tag within the <body> tag?

Comment: i use css not implement in html code and its work for me. Create a new css file such as mystyle.css and link it in your html like <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"> check my first comment.

Comment: Yes please do so if you can. I will try it. Because im unable to find a solution or understand why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div id="Intro">
                <div class="container text-right">
                This is page is created with bootstrap
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="padding-left:140px;">
                        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Industries <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">For Teams</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">API</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="padding-right:67px;">
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" style="border-radius:12px;background:#3793EE;color:white;">Start free trial</button>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   
     .navbar-inverse { 
       background-color : #fffff;
       border-color:transparent;
       background: #ffffff;
       url('bgimg.gif') repeat-x;
    }
    #Intro{
        background:#808080;
        color:#ffffff;
        padding:10px; 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Hi @DemoDemo I copied this code but the same problem. It completely changes the layout like so- https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/2875127/7e7b0fff2433da4cc147787ee16835ed   Please tell me if i did something wrong or if there is a solution.

Comment: I have tried this in multiple ways. Does not work at all, why is the navbar-fixed-top for?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="cs-topbar">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top clearfix">
        <div id="Intro">
            <div class="container text-right">
            This is page is created with bootstrap
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>.cs-topbar{clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;}</style>
```